# Error when inserting to MSQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, class

I have the following code which collects data (same class) from fields in the layout and tries to put it inside a msqlite database :

```
public void submitOrder(Order order_) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colName,      order_.name);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colLink,      order_.link);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colPrice,     order_.price);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colDateYear,  order_.year);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colDateMonth, order_.month);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colDateDay,   order_.day);

        db.insert(DatabaseHelper.orderTable, null, cv);
    db.close();
```

And i have the MSQlite database helper Class i've created :

```
package com.Sagi.MyOrders;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final String dbName="DBname";
static final String orderTable="Orders";
static final String colName="OrderName";
static final String colLink="OrderLink";
static final String colDateYear="DateYear";
static final String colDateMonth="DateMonth";
static final String colDateDay="DateDay";
static final String colPrice="OrderPrice";
static String CREATE_T;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, dbName, null,1);
}
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        CREATE_T="CREATE TABLE orderTable ("
                + "colName TEXT,"
                + "colLink TEXT,"
                + "colPrice TEXT,"
                + "colDateYear INTEGER,"
                + "colDateMonth INTEGER,"
                + "colDateDay INTEGER);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_T);
        Log.e("Table creator","Table Created successfully");
     }
```

When i run it and click on the button to store the info in the DB, i get an error message :

```
06-02 06:19:43.454: E/Database(1570): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Orders has no column named OrderPrice: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Orders(DateDay, DateMonth, OrderLink, OrderName, OrderPrice, DateYear) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

And an I level message :

```
06-02 06:19:43.444: I/Database(1570): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table Orders has no column named OrderPrice
```

Hope you can help ... thanks !

Comment: Clear data or unistall app then it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says `table Orders has no column named OrderPrice`. The reason is you don't update your database. Simply Uninstall/ReInstall your app. And everything will be ok.

After your edit:

You create your table with

```
CREATE_T="CREATE TABLE orderTable ("
                + "colName TEXT,"
                + "colLink TEXT,"
                + "colPrice TEXT,"
                + "colDateYear INTEGER,"
                + "colDateMonth INTEGER,"
                + "colDateDay INTEGER);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_T);
```

Which means you create a table called `orderTable`.

But in your insert:

```
public void submitOrder(Order order_) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colName,      order_.name);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colLink,      order_.link);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colPrice,     order_.price);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colDateYear,  order_.year);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colDateMonth, order_.month);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.colDateDay,   order_.day);

        db.insert(DatabaseHelper.orderTable, null, cv); // This line
    db.close();
```

You use `DatabaseHelper.orderTable` which is `static final String orderTable="Orders";`
 They are not equal so you are getting this error.

Change your orderTable variable or the table name, then you will be ok

Hope this helps

Comment: Well , it seems to give me another step,
I get now the following errors :
    06-02 06:50:02.646: I/Database(328): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: Orders

Comment: Thanks.
I've seen it doesn't handle very well when i create my table columns using vars, 
so i changes it to Strings and it all works now .. 
Too bad, columns names by strings is much more organized.